# Why the ".precision" method from "MulticlassMetrics" object is taking so much time?

Tags: pyspark

I noticed that the time to compute the precision of a model is almost as long as the the time for creating the model itself and this doesn't seem right. I have a cluster with six virtual machines. The most expensive in time is the first iteration from "for item in range(numClasses)" loop. What rdd operations are supposed to happen behind this ?

Code:

```
%pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTree
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics  
from timeit import default_timer

def decision_tree(train,test,numClasses,CatFeatInf):
    ref = default_timer()
    training_data = train.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[-1], row[:-1])).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
    testing_data = test.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[-1], row[:-1])).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
    print 'transformed in dense data in: %.3f seconds'%(default_timer()-ref)

    ref = default_timer()
    model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(training_data, 
                                         numClasses=numClasses, 
                                         maxDepth=7,
                                         categoricalFeaturesInfo=CatFeatInf,
                                         impurity='entropy', maxBins=max(CatFeatInf.values()))
    print 'model created in: %.3f seconds'%(default_timer()-ref)

    ref = default_timer()
    predictions_and_labels =  model.predict(testing_data.map(lambda r: r.features)).zip(testing_data.map(lambda r: r.label))
    print 'predictions made in: %.3f seconds'%(default_timer()-ref)

    ref = default_timer()

    metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictions_and_labels)


    res = {}
    for item in range(numClasses):
        try:
            res[item] = metrics.precision(item)
        except:
            res[item] = 0.0
    print 'accuracy calculated in: %.3f seconds'%(default_timer()-ref)
    return res
```

> transformed in dense data in: 0.074 seconds
>
> model created in: 355.276 seconds
>
> predictions made in: 0.095 seconds
>
> accuracy calculated in: 346.497 seconds

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that are some unfinished rdd operations that are executed when I first call metrics.precision(0)